# Positive linear mapping with values in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let us take a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ that is differnetiable at $x_0\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

We denote by its derivative $df(x_0)$ and we know that this is actually a continuous linear mapping such that
$$f(x_0+h) = f(x_0) + df(x_0)h + o(h),$$
for all $h\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

In one book, I have found the expression that :
$$ df(x_0)\geq 0$$

Does it mean that $df(x_0)h\geq 0$ for every $h\in \mathbb{R}^n$ ?

And if so doesn't this mean thta necessarly $df(x_0)=0$ (the null linear mapping) ?

Comment: It really depends on context; could you quote the text more? And to answer the last question, yes if for each $h$, we have $df(x_0)(h)\geq 0$, then $df(x_0)=0$ (because we apply the inequality to $-h$ as well). It might also mean that for every $h$ with positive components, $df(x_0)(h)\geq 0$ (this is equivalent to each partial derivative being $\geq 0$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derivative of $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is a vector. It can be zero, but in general there is no standard concept of a "positive vector", so you'll probably have to dig into that book to see what was the author thinking about when they wrote "$df(x_0)\geq 0$". One possible interpretation is what you wrote -- which means that it represents a positive linear functional; another plausible interpretation could be that all of its entries are positive.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. The entries of this vector (derivative of $f$) are partial derivatives. So this means that every partial derivative is positive?